# How many database connections are used by GeoServer group layer?

Tags: postgis, geoserver

Does GeoServer use a connection to my PostGIS database for every layer in a group layer?

I have a Tomcat JNDI configuration with a maximum pool-size of 25.
One of these group-layers has for example 9 layers.
Every layer is in the same workspace and used the same data store.
All of them are via JNDI PostGIS.

Will all layers be processed sequentially or in parallel?

Answer (score 5):

Data retrieval during rendering is processed sequentially. One connection should be active for that one WMS request, regardless of how many layers/groups are in the request.

However, the connection pool will hold as many as configured in the store panel, to avoid closing and re-opening them all the time.